# How to escape elements while get html() jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="template">
    <p id="para">
        <h3>I should not come in html</h3>

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.


    </p>
    <h1>Only comes in html</h1>
</div>
```

**Note-**

I want to take whole html of div `#template` except element `#para` in it.

How do I filter this using jQuery?

My jQuery try for this-

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append(function(){
        $('#template').html().filter($('#para').html());
    });
});
```

fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/JM9nH/

Comment: I would suggest reading the jQuery API Documentation before asking question with code full of errors. `append` method when used with a function expect the function to return a string/element/jquery element see http://api.jquery.com/append/. `html` returns a string, strings do not have a `filter` method see http://api.jquery.com/html/.

Comment: Why don't you use this ? $('body').not('#para').html() 

Simply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up all your html is `invalid` .`there is a div in p tag` we can not nested p tag in a div tag

### HTML

```
<div id="template">
    <div id="para">
         <h3>I should not come in html</h3>

        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    </div>
     <h1>Only comes in html</h1>

</div>
```

### JS

```
var getHtmlData=$('#template').children().filter(function(i,val){
   return !(this.id=="para");
});
$('#template').html(getHtmlData);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JM9nH/7/)

### OP

```
Only comes in html
```

Use `children` to select direct children of parent,  and using   `filter` to remove the unwanted children of selected element

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want

```
$("#template").children().not("#para").html();
```

You shouldn't put h3's inside paragraphs though... your [jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/JM9nH/6/) (look at the console)

Comment: You could also use `$('#template > :not(#para)').html()`.